# Ubuntu Server can't boot

Tags: server, virtualization, 16.04, vmbuilder

I have created an Ubuntu 16.04 Server image with `python-vm-builder` but when booting it hangs at `Booting from Hard Disk`.

Here's the vmbuilder log: http://termbin.com/bkar

What is wrong?

**UPDATE:**
fstab:

```
# <file system>                                 <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
UUID=824ce6af-e55e-4151-88cc-3351bd3004ff                                /        ext4    defaults    0    0
UUID=da17fa5e-9f5e-4cdc-8024-1874c293aa8e                                swap        swap    defaults    0    0
```

Comment: Where is the boot stuck?

Comment: @Motte001 KVM won't start the image at all, I'm trying to find a log.

Comment: @Motte001 There's a `dmsetup` error (`['dmsetup', 'info', 'loop10pp1']` gives: `Device does not exist. Command failed`) at the end of the vmbuilder log file, could it be this?

Comment: @Motte001 The image couldn't start because is was a qcow3 image instead of a qcow2 image. Now it can start, but I still have boot problems. It hangs at Booting from Hard Disk.

Comment: maybe the entries in `/etc/fstab` are wrong

Comment: @Motte001 How do I test this? I have updated the question with fstab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the image was in qcow 3 format.